# Ubuntu 20.04 battery drain during hibernation

Tags: laptop, battery, hibernate

I have ASUS Zenbook UX425. This device runs on i7-1065G7 processor on 67Wh battery. This provides hours of regular work using Firefox/Chrome on Ubuntu 20.04. The problem comes when the notebook hibernates. The battery is drained faster than when the notebook is under workload.

I have read the forums and done the following:

1. check "Wake on LAN" (in order to turn it off), but BIOS doesnt offer this option
2. set hibernate mode when the lid is closed

Further, I am taking advantage of Ubuntu 20.04 and its kernel to stop charging when the battery reaches 60% to prevent wear (the notebook is quite often on charger).

(y axis -> 60% battery is maximum)
[image]

---

**QUESTION**

How to debug this issue?